# SD card reader not working on Debian

Tags: linux, sd-card, card-reader

I'm using Debian for about 6 months and my card reader never worked. I tried several solutions I found online with no luck.

How can I make it work?

Here's the output generated by `lspci`

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200/2nd Generation Core Processor Family PCI Express Root Port (rev 09)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 05)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 05)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev b5)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 PCI Bridge (rev b5)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 6 (rev b5)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 05)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation H61 Express Chipset Family LPC Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family SATA AHCI Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 05)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK106 [GeForce GTX 660] (rev a1)
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GK106 HDMI Audio Controller (rev a1)
03:00.0 PCI bridge: Integrated Technology Express, Inc. Device 8892 (rev 10)
05:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 06)
```

And the output from `lsusb`

```
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 058f:6364 Alcor Micro Corp. AU6477 Card Reader Controller
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 045e:0745 Microsoft Corp. Nano Transceiver v1.0 for Bluetooth
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 056a:0302 Wacom Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 045e:028e Microsoft Corp. Xbox360 Controller
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 1a40:0101 Terminus Technology Inc. 4-Port HUB
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

`dmesg` when I insert a card:

```
[74699.879295] ufs was compiled with read-only support, can't be mounted as read-write
[74896.798080] ufs was compiled with read-only support, can't be mounted as read-write
[74923.089671] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] No Caching mode page found
[74923.089677] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] Assuming drive cache: write through
[74923.092706] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] No Caching mode page found
[74923.092711] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] Assuming drive cache: write through
[74923.105427]  sdc: sdc1 sdc2 sdc3
[74923.105895] ufs was compiled with read-only support, can't be mounted as read-write
[74999.985570] sdc: detected capacity change from 15707668480 to 0
[76189.915019] systemd-hostnamed[2816]: Warning: nss-myhostname is not installed. Changing the local hostname might make it unresolveable. Please install nss-myhostname!
```

Comment: What's the dmesg output when you insert a card?

Comment: @ernie I just posted it.

Comment: Looks like the card reader is working, you just can't mount the filesystem read/write.  Have you tried mounting it manually with just read, e.g. `sudo mount -t ufs -o ro,ufstype=ufs2 /dev/sdc1 /mnt/point/here`?  Or tried a different card that's not in UFS?

Comment: @ernie think you can write it as an answer.... will be helpful for other people to found your answer

Comment: sure . . . it was really just a stab in the dark, and it's not 100% clear that that's the answer, but I'll throw it out there.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the card reader is working, you just can't mount the filesystem read/write. Have you tried mounting it manually with just read, e.g. `sudo mount -t ufs -o ro,ufstype=ufs2 /dev/sdc1 /mnt/point/here`? Or tried a different card that's not in UFS?